# Declaring Jquery variables at beginning of script

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I would like to declare several variables at the beginning of my script. As I understand it a global variable can only be created outside of a function anyways. Below is a snippet of code I am using. when the declaration of $map is at position 2 only then the code executes as expected but when at position 1 it does not work. Apart from the downside of being unable to group my declarations I would like to know what is the cause of this difference and what consequences it has

```
var transMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
var homeMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
var $map = $('svg > g'); //1
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $map = $('svg > g'); //2
    zoomSVG($map, 2);
});
```

Comment: Please define what *"does not work"* means in this context. I see no syntax errors in your code (provided jQuery has been loaded) so as far as I can tell, all your code *works*

Comment: Note that you have 2 unrelated `$map` variables (the on defined inside `ready` handler and one global).

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your approach in `1` is, it is executed before the dom is ready at that point of time we are not sure whether the referenced element is loaded so it may not return any element that is the reason to add jQuery code inside a dom ready callback.

So the safest method will be to add all variables that tries to fetch a dom element in the dom ready handler

Comment: +1. Note: the only reason "we are not sure whether the referenced element is loaded" is because OP did not specify where this script is located, otherwise it is pretty well defined that script will not see elements located *after* it in the HTML order (or obviously created via script that runs later).